# Combining two pseudo classes

Tags: css

I have a div element that sets any text withing to upper case.

I need to add another div within the first div but any text within should be properly capitalized. The only way I can do that is by adding the following two:

```
text-transform:lowercase; 
text-transform:capitalize
```

It works, but is there a better way to combine these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `text-transform:none` to override the parent setting.

Comment: It will work, but my second div can sometimes have all upper case words.

Comment: It should not affect the natural letter case

Answer (score 0):

Constrain the two different types of text:

http://jsfiddle.net/eMaCd/

```
<div>
<p class="caps">This is the text to capatalize</p>
<p>Normal Text</p>
</div>​

.caps { text-transform:uppercase; }​
```